# Dictionaries and Maps in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, dictionary

This problem accrued while solving a problem in Hackerrank. The  problem statement is [here](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/30-dictionaries-and-maps). We can solve this problem using Java (using Map and HashMap) or Python. But while i try to solve the problem in PHP, i am getting a termination error. This is because the code is taking too long to execute. For a smaller file size the code is working properly but for larger one it is giving error (Terminated due to time out). How Mapping is done in PHP? Is the code is wrong? Is there any better way to optimize or get the code working properly?

The sample code is below

```
<?php
$myFile = 'text1.txt'; 
$lines = file($myFile); //file as array
$n = (int)$lines[0];
$array = array();
$check = array();

foreach ($lines as $line)
{
    list($key, $value) = explode(' ', $line);
    if ($value !== NULL)
    {
        $array[$key] = $value;
    }
    else {
          $check[]=trim($line);
    }
}
$len=sizeof($check);

for($i=1;$i<$len;$i++) {
$flag=0;
    foreach ($array as $key => $value){
        if($key===$check[$i]) {
            $flag=1;
            echo $key.'='.$value.'<br />';
            break;
        }
    }
    if($flag===0)
    echo 'Not found <br />';
    $flag=0;
}

?>
```

> **A sample input to the file**

File one [Download text1.txt file here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B8nK5L1wBlC6QVdsdHhELWpvWWs)
File two [Download text.text file here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B8nK5L1wBlC6S0tfd1Y2M20tRG8)

> ***Note: text1.txt file is working and the problem is with text.txt
>   file(larger file).***

Comment: it will explode the value sam 99912222, sam as key and phone number as value. that is working fine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For anyone who wonders what the question is:

You have a input like this:

```
1
taha 1234567
paksu
sam
taha
```

and the asker wants you to fill your phone list with n (the first integer) records, then check for the given keys from the input. the query count is variable. And the asker wants you to write

```
name=number
```

if the record exists, or

```
Not found
```

if it doesn't.

---

Check this code:

```
<?php
$_fp = fopen("php://stdin", "r");
$n = intval(fgets(STDIN));
$dict = [];
for($i=0;$i<$n;$i++){
    $vars = explode(" ", fgets(STDIN));
    $dict[trim($vars[0])] = trim($vars[1]);
}
while(!feof(STDIN)){
    $str = trim(fgets(STDIN));
    if(isset($dict[$str])){
        echo $str . "=" . $dict[$str]."\n";
    }else{
        echo "Not found\n";
    }
}

?>
```

It passes all the tests. It's not about PHP, it's how you write your algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$_fp = fopen("php://stdin", "r");
$n = intval(trim(fgets(STDIN)));
$phoneBook = [];
for ($i=0; $i<$n; $i++){
    $lines = trim(fgets(STDIN));
    $arr = explode(" ", $lines);
    $phoneBook[$arr[0]] = $arr[1] ;
}
$query=trim(fgets(STDIN));
do{
if(array_key_exists($query,$phoneBook)){
    echo $query,"=",$phoneBook[$query],"\n";
}
else{
    echo "Not found\n";
}
}while($query=trim(fgets(STDIN)));
?>
```

Here's my solution.